# Looping with regex (Python) appending after match to a list

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop

So I'am trying to append every match of a string into a list with regex.
So here is my code. It only doesn't work (properly) unfortunatly.

```
seq = 'ABABABBBASHDBDHBEHDBEDH'
Empty_list = []
regex_ex = re.finditer(r'.{3}', seq)
for x in regex_ex:
    Empty_list.append(x)
```

Comment: It only doesn't work (properly) , what you expect?

Comment: You can just convert the list of matches to a list instead of appending.

Comment: are you trying to split the string into 3character substrings, put in a list?  that's what the regex looks like anyway.  that's a hammer having a go at some screws - i.e. probably not the best tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access the value of your match you should use [re.Match.group](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.Match.group) method:

```
for x in regex_ex:
    Empty_list.append(x.group())
```

you could replace your `for` loop code with a list comprehension:

```
Empty_list = [x.group() for x in  re.finditer(r'.{3}', seq)]
print(Empty_list)
```

**output:**

```
['ABA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'SHD', 'BDH', 'BEH', 'DBE']
```

if you want a more compact code:

```
list(map(re.Match.group, re.finditer(r'.{3}', seq)))
```

output:

```
['ABA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'SHD', 'BDH', 'BEH', 'DBE']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saving match object instead of matched string:

```
seq = 'ABABABBBASHDBDHBEHDBEDH'
Empty_list = []
regex_ex = re.finditer(r'.{3}', seq)
for x in regex_ex:
    Empty_list.append(x.group(0)) # saves matched string
print(Empty_list)
```

Output:

> ['ABA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'SHD', 'BDH', 'BEH', 'DBE']